# Suggestions with designing search form in an Ember app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So let's say I have 2 routes: `/feeds` and `/groups`. I want to have a search feature in the feeds route where I can search for things like groups (but potentially many more than just simply groups).

I can do a search in feeds route and link it to `/groups/group_1`. The problem now is if I have a back button that links to `/feeds` it will load the route from scratch removing the previous search form. This breaks the user experience and I'm having trouble finding a way to make it work.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to design this in an Ember app? This search behavior is very common to native apps in Android and iOS (e.g. Facebook, Google+, etc.).

The only thing I could think of is to have 1 big route for everything which just makes things cluttered and a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the search string in a [query parameter](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/query-params/). This way the search string will be serialized in the URL and the back button should lead to a page with a filled out search form.